# group by and order by in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table with 4 fields  and 3 Records below query working fine but i want order by `a.start_date` before group by

```
Tabel Name : testdata
Table fields : data type
id: autoincrement,primary key
pattern : varchar
start_date : datetime
cost : decimal(10,5)
```

Records :

```
ID | Pattern | Start_date | Cost
1  | 1       | 2013-09-15 | 10.00
2  | 1       | 2013-09-04 | 15.00
3  | 1       | 2013-09-21 | 28.00
```

QUERY:

```
select a.*, b.cost AS future_cost, b.start_date AS future_date
FROM testdata a
LEFT JOIN testdata b ON a.pattern = b.pattern AND a.id <> b.id
GROUP BY a.pattern
```

Current Output:

```
id  | pattern | start_date | cost | future_date | future_cost
1   |  1      | 2013-09-15 | 10.00| 2013-09-04  | 15.00
```

Required Output:

```
id  | pattern | start_date | cost | future_date | future_cost
2   |  1      | 2013-09-04 | 15.00| 2013-09-15  | 10.00
```

what i need is, in above example earliest date is `2013-09-04` so future date will be `15`, if i delete the record of `2013-09-04` then start date should be `2013-09-15` and future date should be `2013-09-21`

what will be my query to get desired output?

Any help and idea will be appreciated.

Comment: Why do you have a group by?  You don't have any aggregate functions.  Just order by start_date and it should work

Comment: @FionaT if i am running this `select a.*, b.cost AS future_cost, b.start_date AS future_date FROM example a LEFT JOIN example b ON a.pattern = b.pattern AND a.id <> b.id ORDER BY a.start_date` then it gives me this result http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e33a1/4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason you're getting 1 row instead of 6 is you are abusing mysql's unique relaxed group by syntax (I won't go into details, but you are not grouping by all non aggregated columns - normally a syntax error).

Basically you want a join of the earliest 2 rows, and you can bend that unique functionality to your will:

```
select a.*, b.cost AS future_cost, b.start_date AS future_date
from (select * from (select * from testdata order by start_date) x group by pattern) a
left join (select * from testdata order by start_date) b
    on a.pattern = b.pattern and a.id != b.id
group by a.pattern
```

See [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ae075/2)

What's going on here is that when group by is used without grouping by all non-aggregate columns mysql returns the (first) row encountered and by selecting from an ordered rowset, you can control which row that is.

Comment: No worries. Note that this is mysql-only kung fu. Good luck :)

Comment: I have small doubt, its not giving me any output for single record. please check this http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ecf75/1 any solution for this ?

Comment: Solved - I converted to a `left join` (didn't realise there could be only one row). Fiddle also updated.

Comment: one more questions if i want to add searching feature than  where i have to add searching condition like `a.pattern = '1'`

Comment: If you only want to search for one `pattern`, the best performing way of modifying this query would be to change both `select * from testdata order by start_date` to `select * from testdata where pattern '1' order by start_date`.

Answer (score 0):

I don't exactly know if this is what you want but you can make a distinct instead of group by I think.

So sth. like:

```
select a.id,distinct(a.pattern),a.start_date,a.cost, b.cost AS future_cost, b.start_date AS future_date
FROM testdata a
LEFT JOIN testdata b ON a.pattern = b.pattern AND a.id <> b.id
order by a.start_date asc
```